# cant update css on server. showing max-age=14400.how to overwrite disable htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cache-control, mod-expires, max-age

here is my htaccess code

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
```

and what i see on browser even clearing browser history

[image]

Comment: Can you not tell CloudFlare to refresh its cache. Its not your site that is doing the caching

Comment: can we overwrite it ? @RiggsFolly

Comment: I presume you mean OVERRIDE. But that would negate the supposed benefits of using CloudFlare in the first place. I assume you are not changing the CSS very often, Right?? And if you are then test your changes on a development server and only update the LIVE Server when you have the changes tested and working

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly